# I'm trying to get this game of Nim to work but I can't figure out why it keeps looping getUserChoice. Does anybody have any idea why this is?

Tags: python, function

When I run this code, I just get getUserChoice repeating over and over and I'm not sure why it won't move on to getComputerChoice. I can't tell if getComputerChoice just doesn't work or if there's another problem with my code. I feel like I've tried everything at this point and I've exhausted all of my resources on Google.

```py
def displaySticks(numSticks):
    print("The game currently looks like this: ")
    print(" %s " % (numSticks * '|'))

def displayInstructions():
    print(
        "This is a game where players take turns taking sticks, starting with 11 sticks. The player who takes the last stick wins.")

def getUserChoice(numSticks):
    valid = False
    sticksToRemove = None
    while not valid:

        sticksToRemove = int(input("How many sticks do you want to remove? "))

        if sticksToRemove > 3:
            print("You can't remove more than three sticks at a time! "
                  "The current stick count is: " + str(numSticks))
        elif numSticks - sticksToRemove < 0:
            print("There aren't that many sticks left! ")
        else:
            valid = True
    return sticksToRemove

def getComputerChoice(sticksToRemove):
    userTurn = getUserChoice
    while userTurn == True and numSticks > 0:
        sticksToRemove = random.randint(1, min(3, numSticks))
        numSticks -= sticksToRemove
        print("The computer removed " + str(sticksToRemove) +
              " sticks! The current stick count is: " + str(numSticks))
    return sticksToRemove

import random
import function

numSticks = 11
sticksToRemove = 0
getUserChoice = True

def main():
    while numSticks > 0:
        function.displayInstructions()
        print('')
        function.displaySticks(numSticks)
        print('')
        function.getUserChoice(numSticks)
        print('')
        function.getComputerChoice(sticksToRemove)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You don't ever use `getUserChoice()` - try this in your `while` loop: `sticksToRemove = function.getUserChoice(numSticks)` instead.

Comment: I recommend looking up how to call functions. To call functions, you simply use getUserChoice(numSticks), there is no need for function.